# Using certificate and private key in Jmeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, certificate, keystore, private-key

I have two file representing a certificate and the related private key. I have to do some tests in Jmeter non-GUI and I don't know how to set this two files separately, because I read that Jmeter uses keystore settings in system-properties file, but I can't merge certificate and private key files in one. Is there some parameters to be set to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't merge certificate and private key files in one

that's not true, you can do this using i.e. [OpenSSL tool](https://www.openssl.org/) like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out jmeterkeystore.p12 -inkey your.private.key -in your.certificate
```

Once done you can add the next lines to [*system.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/jmeterkeystore.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_keystore_password_here
```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: I know that it is possible to merge the files, but my service logic does not allow me to do this, because jmeter finds the certificates directly in a sub-directory. The certificate and the private key are generated automatically in this sub-directory distinctly and I can't act on this behavior.